# Create installer for .NET Maui app on iOS - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, deployment, maui, ipa

I need help in generating the .ipa file.

I tried to generate the .ipa file by following the next steps:

- I switched from Debug to Release
- in .csproj I checked "Build ipa" from IPA OPTIONS.
- I cleaned/rebuild the solution
- Right-click on the project and select deploy

I verified in the bin/Release folder for the .ipa file but it wasn't generated and I don't receive any errors.

Can somebody help?

Comment: You could try my answer which worked well for me. If you still have any question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, publishing is only supported through the .NET command line interface.

To publish your app, open a terminal and navigate to the folder for your .NET MAUI app project.

You could then use the following command as an example

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-ios -c:Release -r ios-arm64 /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true
```

The .ipa will be generated by default in bin/Release/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/publish/ Folder.

For more info, you could refer to [Publish a .NET MAUI app for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0)

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Select **Release** and **Generic Device** and select **Archive for publishing**.

After the archive finishes select **Sign and Distribute** and select **Ad Hoc**. Then you will create a valid .ipa file.

hope that helps.